# Как в aiogram 3 в middleware получить переменные определенные в хендлере?

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Мне нужно чтобы в каждом хендлере, в конце, в `state` записывалось id последнего сообщения.Можно писать конечно в конце каждого `await state.update_data(last_msg_id=msg.message_id)`, но хочется поменьше дублированного кода. Вот пример хендлера:

```
async def create_hropster_0(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Menus.create_hropster)
    msg = await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, 'Enter the name:')
    await state.update_data(last_msg_id=msg.message_id)
```

Нужно получить переменную `msg` и сохранить ее в `state`.